# Dynamics 365 static marketing list problem

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

In a static marketing list, targeted at the Contact entity, I click "Manage members". Then I choose the option "Remove using advanced find". Any condition I set in the next window, does not work. Even if I don't set any conditions (so after clicking "Find" I should see all the contacts), the result is 0 contacts.

But if I choose the option "Add using advanced find", and I don't set conditions, it correctly finds all the contacts.

Is this a bug? Thank you.

Comment: Does your marketing list have contacts associated (marketing list members)?

Comment: @Ryan James no, it's a new static marketing list that I save, and then click on "manage members"

Comment: Ah you mean the  search is done amongst the  current members list? @Ryan James

Comment: Yep, see my answer below :)

Comment: @Ryan James thanks a lot!

Comment: no worries mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on `Remove using Advanced Find`, the advanced find is in the context of the marketing list members. You are seeing zero results because you have no members in the marketing list.

When you click `Add using Advanced Find` the advance find is in the context of all the contacts you have that you could possibly add as members to the marketing list.

I don't think this is a bug.